# Can 'outgrow' be used to metaphorically mean 'overcome'?

Tags: meaning

I have this gut feeling that 'outgrow' can be used here, but the definitions seem to be completely different.
"Growing up without a father has affected many aspects of my life, but I later learnt how to outgrow my weak points. "

"Growing up without a father has affected many aspects of my life, but I later learnt how to overcome my weak points. "

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of written instances of [*outgrew the bad habit*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22outgrew+the+bad+habit%22) in Google Books (even more for plain [*outgrew the habit*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22outgrew+the+habit%22)). And I can't see any signigficant difference between *bad habits* and *weak points*. But it looks clumsy in your exact context because you already used ***growing up*** earlier in the same sentence. I wouldn't say *outgrow* and *overcome* are exactly "synonymous" in such contexts, though. They have somewhat different implications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Outgrow* and *overcome* have slightly different meanings, with *overcome* suggesting more effort and *outgrow* natural change with greater maturity. Hence *overcoming* something is more impressive than *outgrowing* something.

*outgrow* suggests something that's a more or less natural change as you get older, either literally growing too big, like clothes, or metaphorically, like outgrowing the need for nappies or youthful rebellion. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outgrow) gives as one definition "to grow too large or too mature for". This is supported by two quotations, one literal "outgrew his best suit" and the other "the need to outgrow the habit of war" (referring to growing out of a habit).

In contrast *overcome* suggests more of a deliberate effort to defeat something.